# New line between array's element in JSON output file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to find a way to add new line between elements of an array. I have a php file which outpust JSON data since I have this line - `header('Content-Type: application/json');` Because of this data is always printed in one line, and `<p>`,`<br>`, `\n` are considered as text instead of codes. The while just runs data from a query which insert values into `$vs['title']` and `$vs['description']`.

How can I make it print like this :

```
Title - my title
Value - my value
```

instead of:

```
 Title - my title Value - my value
```

Part of PHP File

```
$vs1=array();
    while($res2 = oci_fetch_array($result2))  {
     $vs=array();
     $vs['title']='Title'.$res2['CATEGORIA_DESC'];
     $vs['description']= 'Value - '.$res2['VALOR'];

 array_push($vs1,$vs);
}

echo str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($vs1), ENT_NOQUOTES));
```

Comment: why do you want new line ? what you have is already valid Json

Comment: I know it is valid and it works, it is just a matter of better display of information, instead of having one long line with everything on it. It's not as pretty and readable.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want display the data, you can do it in the while loop :

```
while ($res2 = oci_fetch_array($result2))  {
    echo "<hr/>";
    echo "<div>Title {$res2['CATEGORIA_DESC']}</div>";
    echo "<div>Value - {$res2['VALOR']}</div>";
}
```